# Zend Autoloader does not work on actual site

Tags: php, zend-framework, bootstrapping, autoloader

having a problem!
I'm using Zend Quickstart application as basement for (just started lol) development.
I have PHP/MySQL server on my local machine (WinXP)
So everything works fine there.
But then I tried to upload my site to remote server. And this is what I get:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Default_Model_Post' not found in /home/mysite/application/controllers/IndexController.php on line 13
```

Line 13:

```
$post = new Default_Model_Post();
```

Default_Model_Post class is located at application/models/post.php
And on my home server it is found by zend app!

I have checked .htaccess - there is SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV production line
Here is my application.ini:

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Mysite_"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts"
resources.db.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username = "mysite_ib"
resources.db.params.password = "my passwd here"
resources.db.params.dbname = "mysite_ib"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true

phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

Here is Bootstrap.php:

```
<?php

class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initAutoload()
    {
        $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
            'namespace' => 'Default',
            'basePath'  => dirname(__FILE__),
        ));
        //print_r( Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getAutoloaders()); exit; //tried to get some info here lol
        return $autoloader;
    }
}
```

Have checked everything I can imagine! It works on my dev machine but on real server - it does not! 
Have searched all over Google, Zend docs and stackoverflow but there's always not exactly my problem (or that fixes do not help).
Also classes in Mysite_ namespace work fine even on real server.
Site on the live server is total copy of my dev site (zipped -> uploaded -> unzipped with zend lib and so on)
Please say how to fix this or at least how to debug it... I'm sure there's some god damned server option that I have forgot to change.
Guys I really rely on your help :( project of my dream is in ruins. Sorry for poor English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every thing looks normal in your post. the only one thing i could think of is make sure the name of the folder "models" is spelled lower case on your server.

You development machine is Windows, so these details may no matter on it but they do matter on Unix.

Comment: Thanks! The problem was really in case-sensitiveness! Both of your answers were usefull!

Answer (score 0):

Your file name should be `Post.php` (capital "P").

As Atef mentioned, Windows file systems are case insensitive so a request for `application/models/Post.php` will resolve to your file.

On a *nix system, the request will fail as the file system is case sensitive.